# Values being skipped while creating multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of words from doing a `preg_split` on a paragraph. I'm trying to compare these words to saved "keywords" stored in each users' profile. As I do a `foreach` on these words, I am having trouble building the array when more than one person has the same keywords.

The database holds something to the extent below.

```html
   id    value 
------+--------
   8      frac
   8       oil
   8    trucks
   9       mud
   9       oil
   9       tar
```

Below is the query I used.

```php
$allwords = preg_split("/(?<=\w)\b\s*/", $sentence);
$matches = array();
foreach ($allwords as $word) {
  $result = db_query('SELECT n.id, n.value FROM {keywords} n WHERE n.value = :fkv', array('fkv' => $word));
  if($result->rowCount()) {
    $usermatch = $result->fetchField(0);
    $matches[$usermatch][] = $word;
  }
}
```

My resulting multidimensional array will pick up `oil` on the first user but not on the second one. For example, my sentence will contain `oil mud trucks`, but the output will look like this:

```php
array
(
  [8] => array
    (
      [0] => oil
      [1] => trucks
    )
  [9] => array
    (
      [0] => mud
    )
)
```

There should be an entry for user 9 that would read `[1] => oil` yet it does not show up. I feel like my foreach is in the wrong spot or i need to reset the loop, but I am at a loss. How do I get the user 9 to show `oil` also?

Comment: You're only fetching one row of results from the query. You need a `while` loop that fetches all the rows of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all the rows returned by the query:

```
foreach ($allwords as $word) {
    $result = db_query('SELECT n.id, n.value FROM {keywords} n WHERE n.value = :fkv', array('fkv' => $word));
    while ($usermatch = $result->fetchField(0));
        $matches[$usermatch][] = $word;
    }
}
```

You don't need to test `rowCount()` first; if the query doesn't match anything, the loop will just end immediately.